# to convert javascript to different Programming languages what do i need?

Tags: converters

if i like to take javascript as base programming language and convert it to something else like java or c++ . what should i need to plan before ?
how does such things works?
how do i parse all the endless ways java script can execute to something like 
java or c++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at titanium which do something similar:
http://www.appcelerator.com/products/

My advice is to write a parser (in java or another language) by using something like jflex and cup.

By doing that, you can transform a language to another one. This is quite difficult though !

Take a look here : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis
and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing